# MySQL: Moving To Barracuda - Error 1118

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert to Barracuda file format with COMPRESSION row format to avoid update issues on a poorly architected table.

This is intended as a stop-gap measure until we can properly re-architect the table.

I have been following instructions found here and in the MySQL documentation to move to InnoDB Barracuda (from Antelope), and have performed the following updates to my configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_file_format_max=Barracuda
innodb_log_file_size=64M
```

After restarting mysql, I then tried the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename>
   ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not
counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the
manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

I have updated all VARCHAR fields to TINYTEXT fields, and checked the total max length in bytes on the table (total: 6766, least: 3178, columns: 384) using the PERL script found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html in the comments (Posted by Rich Tomasso on April 5 2005 4:30pm).

I have also tried creating a new table with a CREATE TABLE command for the given table structure, in the hopes of then re-importing the data after the new data was created using the compressed row format, but the CREATE TABLE statement fails with the same error as above.

Since this is a legacy database, I would like to avoid re-importing, splitting the table up, or any other major re-work if possible.

Any ideas how I can move forward and complete the conversion to Barracuda for this table?

Comment: I think this is a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

So, for me the temporary solution was converting the offending table to MyISAM format. The alter table statement

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename>
    ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

worked just fine. Since we weren't using foreign keys on it, we didn't have a problem there.

We will move back to InnoDB when we restructure and optimize the database architecture.

Comment: You could have installed TokuDB engine and convert to that, you'd get huge compression boost along with performance. If you're interested in that, I suggest googling it.